# Prevent style inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The `ToolTip` from the following XAML is showing with a red background (as a result of the 'global' `Background` style property set on `TextBlock`.

Coming from an HTML/CSS background I'm struggling to see if it's possible to make the `ToolTip` use a different background (or any other customization for that matter) without explicitly setting a custom `Style` key on every `TextBlock` inside a `ToolTip`

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
    <Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock>My Tooltip</TextBlock>
        </Rectangle.ToolTip>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Could you define default style for tooltips?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, but I don't think that would change `TextBlock`s inherited style inside the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add empty style for `TextBlock` to rectangle resources, like this:

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" />
    </Rectangle.Resources>
    <Rectangle.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock>My Tooltip</TextBlock>
    </Rectangle.ToolTip>
</Rectangle>
```

If you want to apply that to all rectangles - do that in your rectangle style:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Red"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" />
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background"
                    Value="Green"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="20"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="20"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Fill"
                    Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
    <Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock>My Tooltip</TextBlock>
        </Rectangle.ToolTip>
    </Rectangle>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is good, but I'm still going to have to define a custom style on every `Rectangle`, so the problem is the same, we're just moving it +1 up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the following line:

```
<Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
```

to `<Style.Resources>` in `Rectangle`'s `Style`. Like this:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for (I was looking for `<Setter Property="Resources"...` wrongly), but Evk just beat you to it

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you want to set custom `Background` or other properties for various `ToolTip's`? If it is what you want, let me show an example:

```
<Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <ToolTip.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ToolTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Style>
                </ToolTip.Style>
                <TextBlock>My Tooltip</TextBlock>
            </ToolTip>
        </Rectangle.ToolTip>
    </Rectangle>
```